# Rails association makes undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models `Airline` and `User`. The problem is that when I try `<%= @current_user.airline.name %>` in a view I get `undefined method 'airline' for nil:NilClass` I have my models set up like this https://gist.github.com/4353169 Maybe I am doing something wrong, but this should work both ways.

Thank you,
Happy holidays (:

Comment: Post your models, please

Comment: @pduersteler they are in https://gist.github.com/4353169 this gist link.

Comment: Can you post the actual development logs? Like a snippet for where that error occurs? Is there a SQL that gets executed before that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a `foreign key` more specified in the Airline class and Check the `foreign key` spelling is correct in the both table.

`User` model,

```
has_one :user, :foreign_key => "uid", primary_key: 'uid', class_name: 'Airline'
```

And in your `Airline` model,

```
belongs_to :airline, foreign_key: 'uid', class_name: 'Airline'
```

It's just the suggestion. Try it....